# PHPhotoLibrary error: content editing in performChanges results in error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, photosframework, photokit

This is the code that I run on viewDidAppear of a brand new swift app. The `info.plist` is setup correctly with the `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` key.

The error I get is `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)`

I can create new assets, delete assets, favorite assets, and revert assets... but attempting to edit their content results in this error. I've been attempting to scour the internet for any clue as to how to go about solving this (Stack Overflow, WWDC videos, the **second** page of google, bing and even *yahoo*).

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status:PHAuthorizationStatus) in

    if status != PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized { return }

    let results = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: nil)
    guard let asset = results.firstObject else { return }

    if asset.canPerform(.content) {

        let inputOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
        inputOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        inputOptions.canHandleAdjustmentData = { (asjustmentData) -> Bool in
            return false
        }

        asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: inputOptions, completionHandler: { (input, info) in
            guard let input = input else { return }

            guard let inputImageURL = input.fullSizeImageURL,
            let inputImage = CIImage(contentsOf: inputImageURL) else { return }

                guard let eagle = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2) else { return }
            let context = CIContext(eaglContext: eagle)
            guard let outputImageRef = context.createCGImage(inputImage, from: inputImage.extent) else { return }
            let outputImage = UIImage(cgImage: outputImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: .right)

            let output = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: input)

            guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(outputImage, 0.9) else { return }
                try! imageData.write(to: output.renderedContentURL, options: .atomic)

            output.adjustmentData = PHAdjustmentData(formatIdentifier: "myFormat", formatVersion: "1.0", data: Data())

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({

                    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest(for: asset)
                    request.contentEditingOutput = output

                }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                    print(success ? "It worked" : "It failed with error:")
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No Errors!")
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**NOTE** on revert, the iOS "Do you want to Edit" dialog appears, however with the code above no dialog appears and the app doesn't crash.

Comment: Hi there. I too can't find a workaround for this nasty bug. I was wondering if you had any luck overcoming this issue. Would you share?

Comment: @user1244109 no luck. Went with a workaround (saving new images) not as nice as editing the image would have been.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
let inputImage = CIImage(contentsOf: inputImageURL) else { return }

// additional code
inputImage = inputImage.applyingOrientation(input.fullSizeImageOrientation)
```

and change "right" to "up".

```
// before
let outputImage = UIImage(cgImage: outputImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: .right)

// after
let outputImage = UIImage(cgImage: outputImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: .up)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error. The fix that worked for me was making sure that  the `Data` passed to the `PHAdjustmentData` actually had some contents. In other words, if it's empty the operation fails.

In my case I don't need to store any real data, so I went with this:

```swift
// ...
let output = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: input)
output.adjustmentData = PHAdjustmentData(
  formatIdentifier: "customImport",
  formatVersion: "1",
  data: "".data(using: .utf8)!
)
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to check the data write to `output.renderedContentURL`.
I get the code because write a data isn't kind of image.